# MongoDB: Find the minimum element in array and delete it

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a documents in MongoDB, one of them looks like this:

```
{
"_id" : 100,
"name" : "Something",
"items" : [
    {
        "item" : 47,
        "color" : "red"
    },
    {
        "item" : 44,
        "color" : "green"
    },
    {
        "item" : 39,
        "color" : "blue"
    }
]
}
```

In every document I need to find the minimum item and delete it. So it should be like this:

```
{
"_id" : 100,
"name" : "Something",
"items" : [
    {
        "item" : 47,
        "color" : "red"
    },
    {
        "item" : 44,
        "color" : "green"
    }
]
}
```

It looks like `findAndModify` function should be used here but I can't go any further.

How to find the minimum element in array and delete it?

I'm using MongoDB and Pymongo driver.

Comment: haha, you doing the 10gen course? week3-2 ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are not restricted to having the query be in one single step, you could try:

step 1) use the aggregate function with the $unwind and $group operators to find the minimum item for each document

```
myresults = db.megas.aggregate( [ { "$unwind": "$items" },  
    {"$group": { '_id':'$_id' , 'minitem': {'$min': "$items.item" } } } ] )
```

step 2) the loop through the results and $pull the element from the array

```
for result in myresults['result']:
    db.megas.update( { '_id': result['_id'] }, 
        { '$pull': { 'items': { 'item': result['minitem'] } } } )
```

Comment: If you want filter like where minimum of red, or green item, you can add {'$match': {"items.color": "red"} } in your aggregate syntax.

Comment: I added following code by mongo shell for(i=0; i<result.length; i++) { db.students.update({ '_id': result[i]['_id']}, { '$pull': { 'items': { 'item': result[i]['minitem'] } } } )  }

Comment: Im able to runt he first query.. Im not able to perform update operation.. Im using for(i=0;i<result.length;i++)

Comment: I had to remove the ['result'] to make it work. The code is like this: for result in myresults:
    db.megas.update( { '_id': result['_id'] }, 
        { '$pull': { 'items': { 'item': result['minitem'] } } } )

Answer (score 9):

Please find my solution written in plain javascript. It should work straight through MongoDb shell

```
cursor = db.students.aggregate(
[{ "$unwind": "$items" }, 
 { "$match": { "items.color": "green"}},
 { "$group": {'_id': '$_id', 'minitem': {
                '$min': "$items.item"
            }
        }
    }

]);

cursor.forEach(
function(coll) {
    db.students.update({
        '_id': coll._id
    }, {
        '$pull': {
            'items': {
                'item': coll.minitem
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: the match statement is optional. But useful to further narrow down a selection from array

Comment: Just to add to the above answers, you could also look into the `for... of` of Javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: above will fetch at a time 20 records what to do to get all records and update them?

Answer (score 0):

Starting in `Mongo 4.4`, the [`$function`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/function/index.html) aggregation operator allows applying a custom javascript function to implement behaviour not supported by the MongoDB Query Language.

And coupled with improvements made to [`db.collection.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#db.collection.update) in `Mongo 4.2` that can accept an aggregation pipeline, allowing the update of a field based on its own value,

We can manipulate and update an array in ways the language doesn't easily permit:

```js
// {
//   "name" : "Something",
//   "items" : [
//     { "item" : 47, "color" : "red"   },
//     { "item" : 39, "color" : "blue"  },
//     { "item" : 44, "color" : "green" }
//   ]
// }
db.collection.update(
  {},
  [{ $set:
    { "items":
      { $function: {
          body: function(items) {
            var min = Math.min(...items.map(x => x.item));
            return items.filter(x => x.item != min);
          },
          args: ["$items"],
          lang: "js"
      }}
    }
  }],
  { multi: true }
)
// {
//   "name" : "Something",
//   "items" : [
//     { "item" : 47, "color" : "red"   },
//     { "item" : 44, "color" : "green" }
//   ]
// }
```

`$function` takes 3 parameters:

- `body`, which is the function to apply, whose parameter is the array to modify. The function here simply consists in first finding the minimum `item` from the array in order to then `filter` it out.
- `args`, which contains the fields from the record that the `body` function takes as parameter. In our case, `"$items"`.
- `lang`, which is the language in which the `body` function is written. Only `js` is currently available.

Comment: Great, great feature actually!