# Removing the minimum element of a particular attribute type in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have the following schemea in MongoDB:

```
{
        "_id" : 100,
        "name" : "John Doe",
        "scores" : [
                {
                        "type" : "exam",
                        "score" : 334.45023
                },
                {
                        "type" : "quiz",
                        "score" : 11.78273309957772
                },
                {
                        "type" : "homework",
                        "score" : 6.676176060654615
                },
                {
                        "type" : "homework",
                        "score" : 35.8740349954354
                }
        ]
}
```

I am looking for a way to remove the homework with the least score. I have found a related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335009/mongodb-find-the-minimum-element-in-array-and-delete-it) but, it doesn't help much as I need to find out only the 'homework' with th least score and remove it.

I am using MongoDB along with the PyMongo Driver.

Comment: This seems to be one of the HW questions from the 10gen MongoDB course .

Comment: @akotian: The homework deadline is already over. You can provide some help/hints. I don't want the solution.

Comment: By the way, the course is rerun two times a year on MongoDB University.

Answer (score 3):

you need to add `match` like:

```
    myresults = scores.aggregate( [ { "$unwind": "$scores" }, { '$match': {'scores.type': "homework" } }, { "$group": { '_id':'$_id' , 'minitem': { '$min': "$scores.score" } } } ] )

    for result in myresults['result']:
        scores.update( { '_id': result['_id'] }, { '$pull': { 'scores': { 'score': result['minitem'] } } } )
```

Comment: I have tried this on mongo shell, but getting syntax error - not sure where is the problem. below is the error :

    for result in myresults['result']:
        scores.update( { '_id': result['_id'] }, {'$pull': { 'scores': { 'score': result['minitem'] } } } )

2014-11-10T01:14:00.573+0530 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 1):

I tried using native mongodb commands and it works.
Use the below 2 commands to make it work.

1)
 cursor = db.students.aggregate([{ "$unwind": "$scores" }, { "$match": { "scores.type": "homework"}},{ "$group": {'_id': '$_id', 'minitem': {'$min':"$scores.score"}}}]), null

2)
cursor.forEach(function(coll) {db.students.update({'_id': coll._id}, {'$pull': {'scores': {'score': coll.minitem}}})})

Comment: The first 1) needs to be modified like this:   cursor = db.students.aggregate( [ { "$unwind": "$scores" },  { "$match": { "scores.type": "homework"}}, 
    {"$group": { '_id':'$_id' , 'minitem': {'$min': "$scores.score" } } } ] )

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using Python:

```py
students = db.students
cursor = students.find({})
for doc in cursor:
        hw_scores = []
        for item in doc["scores"]:
            if item["type"] == "homework":
                hw_scores.append(item["score"])
        hw_scores.sort()
        hw_min = hw_scores[0]
        students.update({"_id": doc["_id"]},
                        {"$pull":{"scores":{"score":hw_min}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible using native mongodb commands.  I think the best way of doing it would be to write a javascript function to drop the lowest score and run it on the server; this would have the advantage of being automic, so that a list couldn't be updated while you were removing from it, keeping things consistent.

Here's some documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/server-side-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

I followed the third answer here. [Removing the minimum element of a particular attribute type in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788317/removing-the-minimum-element-of-a-particular-attribute-type-in-mongodb?lq=1)

```
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/school', function(err, db) {
      if(err) throw err;

      var students = db.collection('students');
      cursor = students.aggregate(
    [{ "$unwind": "$scores" }, 
     { "$match": { "scores.type": "homework"}},
     { "$group": {'_id': '$_id', 'minitem': {
                    '$min': "$scores.score"
                }
            }
        }

    ]);

    cursor.forEach(
    function(coll) {
        students.update({
            '_id': coll._id
        }, {
            '$pull': {
                'scores': {
                    'score': coll.minitem
                }
            }
        })
    });
    });
```