# mongodb filtering the first subarray in several documents

Tags: mongodb

I have the various documents mongodb like this.

this is the document.

```
    {
        "_id" : 22,
        "stock" : [
            {
                "id" : "41u",
                "qty" : 10,
                "price":12
            },
            {
                "id" : "65u",
                "qty" : 14,
                "price":37
            }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : 52,
        "stock" : [
            {
                "id" : "34u",
                "qty" : 10,
                "price":33
            },
            {
                "id" : "89u",
                "qty" : 14,
                "price":96
            }
        ]
}
```

In all documents I need to find the minimum element . Therefore , you must be:

```
   {
            "_id" : 22,
            "stock" : [
                {
                    "id" : "41u",
                    "qty" : 10,
                    "price":12
                }
            ]
    }
    {
            "_id" : 52,
            "stock" : [
                {
                    "id" : "34u",
                    "qty" : 10,
                    "price":33
                }
            ]
    }
```

I am again with mongodb
mongodb in the documentation I found examples of mapreduce ,
I welcome your comments

Comment: what is resto.en?  Please edit question with expected output as your question is not much clear.

Comment: I want to filter the field stock .the array ( price = > 0.00 )
less the rest.

Comment: May be English is not your native language. So, please edit you question with expected output  as it's still unclear to me

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to tell you, map reduce jobs are for **distributed systems & large dataset**. According to MongoDB's documentation:

> For most aggregation operations, the Aggregation Pipeline provides
>   better performance and more coherent interface. However, map-reduce
>   operations provide some flexibility that is not presently available in
>   the aggregation pipeline.

Since you are not applying complex functions and I am assuming you are not making a cluster or in other words in distributed system, you can use [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) (*correct me if my assumption is wrong*).

Now coming to your question, please [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335009/mongodb-find-the-minimum-element-in-array-and-delete-it) this similar question.