# MongoDB remove object from array deletes complete array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object

I have a document like this one:

```
{
        "_id" : 0,
        "name" : "aimee Zank",
        "scores" : [
                {
                        "type" : "exam",
                        "score" : 1.463179736705023
                },
                {
                        "type" : "quiz",
                        "score" : 11.78273309957772
                },
                {
                        "type" : "homework",
                        "score" : 6.676176060654615
                },
                {
                        "type" : "homework",
                        "score" : 35.8740349954354
                }
        ]
}
```

On that document I want to delete the score that has the lowest score of type homework. First, I'm trying to do it on the mongo shell, so I put the values manually.

```
 db.students.update({ _id:0}, {$unset: {"scores.score":6.676176060654615} })
```

That query does nothing, so I tried to search on Google and I found here a question about removing an object from an array and I tried this other query:

```
db.students.update({ _id:0 }, { $unset: 
                                   { "scores": { 
                                        "homework": 6.676176060654615 } } }, false, true);
```

The second query worked, but not as I expected because the result was

```
{ "_id" : 0, "name" : "aimee Zank" }
```

To check that the lowest value of type homework exists I find with this query:

```
db.students.find({"scores.score":6.676176060654615}).pretty();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete/pull only `score = 6.676176060654615`, you need to simply use following query :

```
db.collection.update({"_id":0},{"$pull":{"scores":{score: 6.676176060654615}}})
```

If you want to find minimum value and remove it from your collection. You need to do this is two steps. For more details [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335009/mongodb-find-the-minimum-element-in-array-and-delete-it)

Comment: This should work to pull `score = 6.676176060654615 `. can you check using find query whether `score = 6.676176060654615` exists or not?

Comment: I edited my question and I added the find that I used to check if exists. Using $min can I get the minimum score of type homework?

Comment: I tried again with the query you provied, because it is similar to one from the link you posted.