# node.js and mongodb find and delete

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

hey guys im new to programming in general and i am trying to write a query in node.js to display the lowest score in my database then later on delete it. my data looks like this

```
{
"_id" : 19,
"name" : "Gisela Levin",
"scores" : [
    {
        "type" : "exam",
        "score" : 44.51211101958831
    },
    {
        "type" : "quiz",
        "score" : 0.6578497966368002
    },
    {
        "type" : "homework",
        "score" : 93.36341655949683
    },
    {
        "type" : "homework",
        "score" : 49.43132782777443
    }
]
}
```

so i need to find and delete just the lowest homework alone and not both. in the code i wrote i am trying to just display these lowest first then i will remove them. so far this code i have written shows both scores like this

> 'Verdell Sowinski scored 69.09840625499065'
>
> 'Verdell Sowinski scored 17.90304994248164'
>
> 'Vina Matsunaga scored 19.16579262350994'
>
> 'Vina Matsunaga scored 8.217818112853726'
>
> 'Vinnie Auerbach scored 23.91300715707971'
>
> 'Vinnie Auerbach scored 53.31631231243156'
>
> 'Whitley Fears scored 92.2308421188758'
>
> 'Whitley Fears scored 97.95928979563497'
>
> 'Wilburn Spiess scored 10.53058536508186'
>
> 'Wilburn Spiess scored 28.10477578379966'
>
> 'Zachary Langlais scored 19.21886443577987'
>
> 'Zachary Langlais scored 8.548735651522431'
>
> 'aimee Zank scored 6.676176060654615'
>
> 'aimee Zank scored 18.52035674134503'

this is what i have so far :

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/school', function(err, db){
    if(err) throw err;

    var cursor = db.collection('students').find().sort({name : 1});
    var list = [];
    var count = 0;
    var currentName = '';

    cursor.each(function(err, doc){
        if(err) throw err;

    if(doc == null){
        return
    }
    
    var lowestScore = 1000;
    var lowestScore_position = '';

    for(i=0; i<doc.scores.length; i++){
        if (doc.scores[i].type == 'homework' && doc.scores[i].score<=lowestScore) {
        lowestScore = doc.scores[i].score;
        lowestScore_position = i;
            
        }
    }
    console.dir(doc.name + " scored " + lowestScore);
    });
});
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: Find the minimum element in array and delete it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335009/mongodb-find-the-minimum-element-in-array-and-delete-it)

Comment: Take a look at the second solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335009/mongodb-find-the-minimum-element-in-array-and-delete-it). Same problem, same data structure.

Comment: It is the MongoDB for node.js developers course homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/school', function(err, db) {
   if (err) throw err;

   var cursor = db.collection('students').find();

   var lastStudent = '';

   cursor.each(function(err, doc){
      if (err) throw err;

      if (doc == null) {
          setTimeout(function() {
              return db.close()
          }, 2000);
      } else {

          var lowScoreIndex = -1;
          var lowScore = 100;

          Array.prototype.forEach.call(doc.scores, function(score) {
              if (score.type === 'homework') {
                  if (score.score < lowScore) {
                      lowScore = score.score;
                      lowScoreIndex = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(score, lowScore);
                  }
              }
          });

          doc.scores.splice(lowScoreIndex, 1);

          db.collection('students').update({'_id':doc['_id']}, doc, function(err, updated) {
              if (err) throw err;
          })
      }

   });
});
```

Comment: thanks for this, you did in such a way that is actually readable and makes sense